# tutorial for installing VimClojure

Tags: clojure, vimclojure

Is there any tutorial/screencast available online for free to figure out how to use/install vimClojure.

Answer (score 2):

There is the online documentation in ~/.vim/doc (see :help helptags).

There is a google group: http://groups.google.com/group/vimclojure

There is me: mailto:mb@kotka.de

Comment: I installed vimclojure today and it really took me quite a while. I had to piece together most of the information necessary to install it from different blogs and websites. It would be very helpful if you had a nice bottom up install tutorial on your website. BTW: Thank's for vimclojure I really like it.

Comment: @nick-klauer removed the link.

Answer (score 1):

here's a screen case referenced in [this clojure wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Getting_Started#Vim)

```
http://blip.tv/file/1884989
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great project called vimclojure-easy available that helps install/configure vimclojure:

https://github.com/daveray/vimclojure-easy

Although not a tutorial per se, it will help you get up and running with vimclojure.